# ERROR: Error installing ffi: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension

Tags: macos, file, makefile, ffi

I am getting this error in Mac 64 bit and have xcode inatalled on machine.

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing ffi:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/Users/jreddy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for ffi.h in /usr/local/include... no
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... no
checking for ruby_thread_has_gvl_p()... no
checking for ruby_native_thread_p()... no
checking for rb_thread_call_with_gvl()... no
creating extconf.h
creating Makefile

make
sh: make: command not found
```

Comment: Re installed xcode tools again! It worked .

Comment: You have to install development tools first.
Could you check if you have XCode Command Line Tools installed?
by running `xcode-select --install`

From here: https://github.com/ffi/ffi/issues/937#issuecomment-1073265562

Answer (score 41):

A large portion of users are landing on this answer in an attempt to update the **Xcode Command Line Tools**. The easiest way to achieve this is by removing the old version of the tools, and installing the new one.

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
xcode-select --install
```

A popup will appear and guide you through the rest of the process.

After all, if **xcode** is installed correctly and you still have a problem, try installing ffi like this:

```
gem install ffi -v '1.9.18' -- --with-cflags="-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration"
```

Comment: `gem install ffi -v '1.9.18' -- --with-cflags="-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration"` works for me. thank you

Answer (score 13):

I use homebrew, so after I did `brew install libffi` the gem installed for me. I have Xcode 4.2 tools active (with xcode-select). I did have to close and open a new Terminal window for home-brew's install to be recognised by the gem installation. But I could only get it working with ruby 1.8.7 but not 1.9.3 (using rvm).

Comment: `brew install ruby` fixed it for me, whereas `brew install libffi` did not.

Answer (score 13):

This one worked for me:

`brew link libffi --force`

Comment: Same. Seems like just installing `libffi` using brew is not enough.

Answer (score 6):

Another version of answer, if you install libffi using brew then still does not work. You can try do this :

```
$ export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/libffi/3.2.14/lib/pkgconfig/
$ gem install ffi
```

Comment: this one helped me (other options didn't)

Answer (score 2):

I am also on OS X Lion. I re-installed XCode and ffi installed successfully using bundle install.

Answer (score 2):

Updating the Command Line Tools within XCode
and following these steps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10610951/1691 did it for me

Comment: I didn't have to follow those extra steps - just updating XCode and running `bundle install` again did the job. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Updating X-code on my Mac OS-X Maverics made it work for me

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem on OSX 10.10.15 with ruby-2.0.0-p481 under rvm.  All i had to do was

```
sudo xcodebuild -license
```

It won't fix all cases but it might fix some

Answer (score 1):

If `gem install ffi -v '1.9.21' --source 'https://rubygems.org/`  did not solve the problem. Then it seems like in Mac ffi-1.19.21 is trying to using ffi_prep_closure_loc() and system-libffi which doesn’t have.

Try this temporary solution:

> `gem install ffi -- --disable-system-libffi`

More details here: https://github.com/ffi/ffi/issues/791

Answer (score 1):

For me, it worked with this,

I had issue with React Native ios when running

```
bundle install
```

An error occurred while installing ffi (1.15.5), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install ffi -v '1.15.5' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.

Resolved this error by doing this.

```
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/libffi/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/libffi/include"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/libffi/lib/pkgconfig"
```

Comment: Where would I place the above `exports` you've listed?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem on OS X Lion and solved it by doing:

```
sudo port install libffi
```

Comment: macports needs to be installed on the system level for it to work with `sudo`.

Answer (score 0):

I was using ree-1.8.7-2010.02 and there was no way the install would work. Switched to ruby-1.9.2 and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, I had to add the following environment variables to my `~/.profile`/`~/.bash_profile`:

```
export SDKROOT=$(xcrun --sdk macosx --show-sdk-path)
export LIBRARY_PATH="/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib"
```

Once I added those, I was able to install the `ffi` Gem.

Note that you may need to install/setup the Xcode SDK/libraries first via:

```
xcode-select --install
sudo xcodebuild -license
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me, first:

```
gem install ffi -v '1.15.5' -- --with-cflags="-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration"
```

Then:

```
gem pristine ffi --version 1.15.5
```