# can't setup ruby environment - installing fii gem error

Tags: ruby, xcode, macos, rubygems

I'm trying to setup environtment for ruby project.
But when I run 'bundle', I have error during installing 'fii' gem:

```
    Installing ffi (1.8.1) 
    Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Users/bmalets/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
    checking for ffi.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
    Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
    necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
    details.  You may need configuration options.

    /Users/bmalets/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:381:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
    You have to install development tools first.

    Gem files will remain installed in /Users/bmalets/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@api2/gems/ffi-1.8.1 for inspection.
    Results logged to /Users/bmalets/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@api2/gems/ffi-1.8.1/ext/ffi_c/gem_make.out

    An error occurred while installing ffi (1.8.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
    Make sure that `gem install ffi -v '1.8.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

My environment:

- OS_X 10.8.4
- ruby 1.9.3p448
- Xcode 4.6.3
- libffi-3.0.13

Please, help me to fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure that you have installed Apple Xcode and Command Line Tools (look at this screenshot):

[image]

https://developer.apple.com/technologies/tools/

After that, don't forget to install libffi.

1) if you are using homebrew

```
brew install libffi
```

2) if you are using macport

```
sudo port install libffi
```

Comment: That's a very common error. I use macports, they are far more flexible than brew and work like a charm if you come from a unix background. If not though, it's better to use brew.

Comment: I have already installed 'libffi' and Xcode. Unfortunately, I can't understand what's the cause of problem((.

Comment: @bmalets May be these steps will help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10610951/595120

Comment: Try to do this steps. Now have the same problem with atomic gem :D

Comment: Did you installed command line tools for xcode? it's accessible via components tab in XCode.