# Install Rails Failed on OSX 10.8.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I always failed to install rails on my new Air with OSX 10.8.4, even I succeed installed ruby2, Command Line Tool of XCode, it still prompts some error when I try to install rails.

I found lots solutions from the Internet, but they all don't work on my issue, I'm completely confused, doesn't any can help me? I'll really appreciate!!!

---

```
    localhost:myapp zerocool$ ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [x86_64-darwin12.3.0]
localhost:myapp zerocool$ sudo gem install rails
Password:
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/zerocool/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby extconf.rb
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/zerocool/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby
    --with-atomic_reference-dir
    --without-atomic_reference-dir
    --with-atomic_reference-include
    --without-atomic_reference-include=${atomic_reference-dir}/include
    --with-atomic_reference-lib
    --without-atomic_reference-lib=${atomic_reference-dir}/
/Users/zerocool/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:434:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /Users/zerocool/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:519:in `try_link0'
    from /Users/zerocool/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:817:in `try_run'
    from extconf.rb:24:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/zerocool/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/atomic-1.1.12 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/zerocool/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/atomic-1.1.12/ext/gem_make.out
```

Comment: it looks like you have `rvm` installed. is there a particular reason you're doing `sudo gem install` instead of `gem install`?

Comment: What are the contents of mkmf.log?

Comment: I use _sudo gem install_ 'cause if I just use _gem install_, it will prompt there's some permission issue.

Comment: I don't know where the mkmf.log is, I use whereis command cannot find it, could you please give the path? Thanks!

Comment: Check this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11802918/error-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension-when-installing-rails-on-mac-mountia It discusses a problem very similar to yours

Comment: What version of xcode do you have installed?

Comment: @amb110395 Yes, I tried, but it doesn't work, the same error still prompts. And I found it should be gem's issue, 'cause even I use _gem update_, the same problem will also happen.

Comment: @Zabba It's XCode 4.6.3. This is my new Mac, so every software is the latest version.

Comment: Did you install the xcode Command Line Tools (http://stackoverflow.com/a/17775189/382818) then restart terminal

Comment: @Zabba Yes, of course.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this issue today and it seems that my download of ruby-2.0.0 did not work properly. I would recommend trying `rvm reinstall 2.0.0` followed by `gem install rails`.

Comment: I had to `rvm get stable`, followed by `rvm reinstall 2.0.0`, but this did the trick for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I got the solution! Run *rvm implode*，and use *rm* to delete /etc/rvmrc and ~/.rmvrc, restart your mac, and you can use *gem install rails* to install rails successfully.

Comment: Be careful with this - rvm implode removes all rvm gemsets from your system, so if you already have projects running on RVM this will *reset* them.

Answer (score 1):

> First I installed gcc via homebrew:
>
> installing gcc on mavericks using brew
>
> `brew tap homebrew/dupes` 
>   `brew install apple-gcc42`
>
> Then I symlinked the newly installed apple-gcc42
>   into my /usr/bin folder
>
> `cd /usr/bin`
>
> `sudo mv gcc gcc_mavs sudo ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/apple-gcc42/4.2.1-5666.3/bin/gcc-4.2 gcc`

Credits: https://coderwall.com/p/lqpp8w

Comment: I've just been having the same issue on El Capitan. For anyone else coming across this on El Capitan, try following these instructions, but skip `sudo mv gcc gcc_mavs`.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error when running against ruby-2.0.0-p195, but updating to ruby-2.0.0-p247 (the current RVM default for 2.0.0) fixed it.