# chef ruby gem installer failing

Tags: ruby, rubygems, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I am trying to setup cassandra on an CentOS VM via chef and it fails with the error below. I have tried [clearing out bundle caches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10575679/bundle-update-fails-on-ffi) to no avail. The recipe works on another machine but a key difference is that I ran other recipes on that machine beforehand so I suspect I am missing a chef dependency (which is why I haven't tried just fixing the packages directly). I am also terribly new to ruby so sorry if this is an obvious question.

Machine config

- Chef: 11.4.0
- ruby 1.9.3p286 (2012-10-12 revision 37165) [x86_64-linux]
- gem 1.8.24
- Linux somehost 2.6.32-276.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue May 29 17:38:19 EDT 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Error messages
chef-client output:

> ```
> Starting Chef Client, version 11.4.0
>     resolving cookbooks for run list: ["chef-client", "cassandra"]
>     Synchronizing Cookbooks:
>       - minitest-handler
>       - chef_handler
>       - yum
>       - cron
>       - selinux
>       - sysctl
>       - openssh
>       - iptables
>       - chef-client
>       - cassandra
>       - apt
>       - java
>       - windows
>       - aws
>     Compiling Cookbooks...
>     Recipe: cassandra::packages
>       * chef_gem[cassandra-cql] action install
>     ================================================================================
>     Error executing action `install` on resource 'chef_gem[cassandra-cql]'
>     ================================================================================
> ```

```
 Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError
    -----------------------------------
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /opt/chef/embedded/bin/ruby extconf.rb
    extconf.rb:25: Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
    checking for strlcpy() in string.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
    Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
    necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
    details.  You may need configuration options.

    Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=/opt/chef/embedded/bin/ruby
    /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:381:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
    You have to install development tools first.
        from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:461:in `try_link0'
        from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:476:in `try_link'
        from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:619:in `try_func'
        from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:894:in `block in have_func'
        from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:790:in `block in checking_for'
        from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
        from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
        from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block in postpone'
        from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
        from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:280:in `postpone'
        from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:789:in `checking_for'
        from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:893:in `have_func'
        from extconf.rb:29:in `<main>'


    Gem files will remain installed in /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thrift-0.9.1 for inspection.
    Results logged to /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thrift-0.9.1/ext/gem_make.out



    Cookbook Trace:
    ---------------
    /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/cassandra/recipes/packages.rb:30:in `block in from_file'
    /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/cassandra/recipes/packages.rb:29:in `each'
    /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/cassandra/recipes/packages.rb:29:in `from_file'
    /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/cassandra/recipes/default.rb:23:in `from_file'


    Resource Declaration:
    ---------------------
    # In /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/cassandra/recipes/packages.rb

     30:   chef_gem pkg do
     31:     action :install
     32:     version attrs["version"] if attrs["version"]
     33:   end
     34: end



    Compiled Resource:
    ------------------
    # Declared in /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/cassandra/recipes/packages.rb:30:in `block in from_file'

    chef_gem("cassandra-cql") do
      provider Chef::Provider::Package::Rubygems
      action [:install]
      retries 0
      retry_delay 2
      package_name "cassandra-cql"
      version "1.1.4"
      cookbook_name "cassandra"
      recipe_name "packages"
    end


    ================================================================================
    Recipe Compile Error in /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/cassandra/recipes/default.rb
    ================================================================================


    Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError
    -----------------------------------
    chef_gem[cassandra-cql] (cassandra::packages line 30) had an error: Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

            /opt/chef/embedded/bin/ruby extconf.rb
    extconf.rb:25: Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
    checking for strlcpy() in string.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
    Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
    necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
    details.  You may need configuration options.

    Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=/opt/chef/embedded/bin/ruby
    /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:381:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
    You have to install development tools first.
        from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:461:in `try_link0'
        from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:476:in `try_link'
        from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:619:in `try_func'
        from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:894:in `block in have_func'
        from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:790:in `block in checking_for'
        from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
        from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
        from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block in postpone'
        from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
        from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:280:in `postpone'
        from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:789:in `checking_for'
        from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:893:in `have_func'
        from extconf.rb:29:in `<main>'


    Gem files will remain installed in /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thrift-0.9.1 for inspection.
    Results logged to /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thrift-0.9.1/ext/gem_make.out



    Cookbook Trace:
    ---------------
      /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/cassandra/recipes/packages.rb:30:in `block in from_file'
      /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/cassandra/recipes/packages.rb:29:in `each'
      /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/cassandra/recipes/packages.rb:29:in `from_file'
      /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/cassandra/recipes/default.rb:23:in `from_file'


    Relevant File Content:
    ----------------------
    /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/cassandra/recipes/packages.rb:

     23:    package pkg do
     24:      action :install
     25:      version attrs["version"] if attrs["version"]
     26:    end
     27:  end
     28:  
     29:  node["cassandra"]["chef_gems"].each do |pkg, attrs|
     30>>   chef_gem pkg do
     31:      action :install
     32:      version attrs["version"] if attrs["version"]
     33:    end
     34:  end
     35:  
     36:  # Some distributed packages of Cassandra start the service in their
     37:  # postinstall; keep them all equal and a restart can be done after the configs
     38:  # are written on the first run. Added difficulty: they also come with init
     39:  # scripts that always exit 0.



    [2013-10-11T13:13:42-04:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
    [2013-10-11T13:13:42-04:00] FATAL: Saving node information to /var/chef/cache/failed-run-data.json
    [2013-10-11T13:13:42-04:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
    Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated
    [2013-10-11T13:13:42-04:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
    [2013-10-11T13:13:42-04:00] FATAL: Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: chef_gem[cassandra-cql] (cassandra::packages line 30) had an error: Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

            /opt/chef/embedded/bin/ruby extconf.rb
    extconf.rb:25: Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
    checking for strlcpy() in string.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
    Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
    necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
    details.  You may need configuration options.

    Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=/opt/chef/embedded/bin/ruby
    /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:381:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
    You have to install development tools first.
        from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:461:in `try_link0'
        from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:476:in `try_link'
        from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:619:in `try_func'
        from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:894:in `block in have_func'
        from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:790:in `block in checking_for'
        from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
        from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
        from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block in postpone'
        from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
        from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:280:in `postpone'
        from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:789:in `checking_for'
        from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:893:in `have_func'
        from extconf.rb:29:in `<main>'</pre>


    Gem files will remain installed in /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thrift-0.9.1 for inspection.
    Results logged to /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thrift-0.9.1/ext/gem_make.out
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
>   You have to install development tools first.

The above error makes me believe you need to install `ruby-dev` and `gcc` packages on your CentOS.
On my ubuntu 10.04, I have installed the packages below:
`ruby1.9.1-dev` and `gcc-4.4`.

Could you try installing similar packages on CentOS and then re-running chef?

Comment: Thank you, that does in fact fix the issue. I still have to see the what chef dependency will do this automatically though.

Comment: In case someone needs it, This is what I ran manually

    yum install gcc gcc-c++ ruby-devel

Comment: The above comment fixed an issue where I was getting the same error when using gem_package on centos 6. Thanks!

Comment: You want to use the [build-essential cookbook](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/build-essential) and set `node['build_essential']['compiletime']` to `true`

Comment: @slayedbylucifer: Could you please elaborate what are the dependencies that needs to be resolved?

Comment: I ran this command ` yum install ruby ruby-devel ruby-ri ruby-rdoc rubygem-chef gcc gcc-c++ automake autoconf make curl dmidecode and gem install chef --no-ri --no-rdoc`. I am still getting the error

Comment: Same for me =( Build-essential didn't help at all.