# Chef install series of pre-packaged gems

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I am trying to install a series of gems required by my recipes but I would rather not install the development tools (i.e. gcc, gcc-c++, ruby-devel. see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19324131/chef-ruby-gem-installer-failing) for more context) on my production machines, so instead have included the relevant gem files as resources in my cookbook.

I am using this code

```
node["chef_gems"].each do |pkg, attrs|
  gem_file = "#{pkg}-#{attrs["version"]}.gem"
  dest_gem_file = "#{Chef::Config['file_cache_path']}/#{gem_file}"
  cookbook_file "#{dest_gem_file}" do
      source "gems/#{gem_file}"
  end
  if File.exist?("#{dest_gem_file}")
    chef_gem pkg do
      source "#{dest_gem_file}"
      action :install
    end
  end
end
```

Issues I am running in to

1. Currently this requires two chef runs because of the File.exist? check but without it, it fails to compile because the file doesn't exist during the compilation phase. Is there a simpler way to accomplish this?
2. Some of these gems have dependencies so ordering matters which seems to default to alphabetical. I am about to go down the path of enforcing order via a sort ordering key (ugly), was wondering if there is a better way.
3. Stepping back, this seems overly complicated. Is there a simpler strategy to achieve the goal of installing the gems and their dependencies without installing development tools on production servers.

Here is the original error without the File.exist? check

```
Starting Chef Client, version 11.4.0
resolving cookbooks for run list: ["cis-rhel", "ec2-hostname-rhel", "chef-client", "cassandra"]
Synchronizing Cookbooks:
<REDACTED>
Compiling Cookbooks...
[2013-10-16T18:45:01-04:00] WARN: Cloning resource attributes for user[<REDACTED>] from prior resource (CHEF-3694)
<REDACTED>
[2013-10-16T18:45:01-04:00] WARN: Current  user[cassandra]: /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/cassandra/recipes/user.rb:23:in `from_file'
Recipe: cassandra::packages
  * chef_gem[cassandra-cql] action install
================================================================================
Error executing action `install` on resource 'chef_gem[cassandra-cql]'
================================================================================


Gem::Exception
--------------
Cannot load gem at [/var/chef/cache/cassandra-cql-1.1.4.gem] in /


Cookbook Trace:
---------------
/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/cassandra/recipes/packages.rb:36:in `block in from_file'
/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/cassandra/recipes/packages.rb:29:in `each'
/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/cassandra/recipes/packages.rb:29:in `from_file'
/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/cassandra/recipes/default.rb:23:in `from_file'


Resource Declaration:
---------------------
# In /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/cassandra/recipes/packages.rb

 36:     chef_gem pkg do
 37:       source "#{dest_gem_file}"
 38:       action :install
 39:     end
 40: #  end



Compiled Resource:
------------------
# Declared in /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/cassandra/recipes/packages.rb:36:in `block in from_file'

chef_gem("cassandra-cql") do
  provider Chef::Provider::Package::Rubygems
  action [:install]
  retries 0
  retry_delay 2
  package_name "cassandra-cql"
  source "/var/chef/cache/cassandra-cql-1.1.4.gem"
  cookbook_name "cassandra"
  recipe_name "packages"
end




================================================================================
Recipe Compile Error in /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/cassandra/recipes/default.rb
================================================================================


Gem::Exception
--------------
chef_gem[cassandra-cql] (cassandra::packages line 36) had an error: Gem::Exception: Cannot load gem at [/var/chef/cache/cassandra-cql-1.1.4.gem] in /


Cookbook Trace:
---------------
  /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/cassandra/recipes/packages.rb:36:in `block in from_file'
  /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/cassandra/recipes/packages.rb:29:in `each'
  /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/cassandra/recipes/packages.rb:29:in `from_file'
  /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/cassandra/recipes/default.rb:23:in `from_file'


Relevant File Content:
----------------------
/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/cassandra/recipes/packages.rb:

 29:  node["cassandra"]["chef_gems"].each do |pkg, attrs|
 30:    gem_file = "#{pkg}-#{attrs["version"]}.gem"
 31:    dest_gem_file = "#{Chef::Config['file_cache_path']}/#{gem_file}"
 32:    cookbook_file "#{dest_gem_file}" do
 33:        source "gems/#{gem_file}"
 34:    end
 35:  #  if File.exist?("#{dest_gem_file}")
 36>>     chef_gem pkg do
 37:        source "#{dest_gem_file}"
 38:        action :install
 39:      end
 40:  #  end
 41:  end
 42:  
 43:  # Some distributed packages of Cassandra start the service in their
 44:  # postinstall; keep them all equal and a restart can be done after the configs
 45:  # are written on the first run. Added difficulty: they also come with init



[2013-10-16T18:45:01-04:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
[2013-10-16T18:45:02-04:00] FATAL: Saving node information to /var/chef/cache/failed-run-data.json
[2013-10-16T18:45:02-04:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated
[2013-10-16T18:45:02-04:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
[2013-10-16T18:45:02-04:00] FATAL: Gem::Exception: chef_gem[cassandra-cql] (cassandra::packages line 36) had an error: Gem::Exception: Cannot load gem at [/var/chef/cache/cassandra-cql-1.1.4.gem] in /
```

Comment: Please don't forget to mark an answer as correct! :)

Answer (score 1):

1. You can and should skip the `if File.exist?("#{dest_gem_file}")` segment, as the previous resource will always create the file or raise an exception.
2. Installing these with a package manager that can deal with dependencies may be a much better option, if you can do that.
3. If it's not possible to do it with the `rubygems` package manager because it needs to compile native extensions for packages, you could consider packaging the compiled versions and using the systems package manager to install them.

Comment: re: 1. I would like to but when I try that I get a recipe compilation error I believe because of the two phase chef processing (i.e. it tries to compile the recipe and fails because the file doesn't yet exist, so never gets to the execution phase in which it would be created). Adding the if is what "fixed" that but still requires two chef runs. I can post the details of that error if you think I am missing something and the previous explanation doesn't make sense.

Comment: No, my mistake - chef_gem installs gems before/during the recipe compilation stage, so that they can be required in the recipe straight away. This is only useful if you intend to use the gem from the chef recipe, else you should use the `gem_package` resource (which wouldn't need the `File.exist?` check).

Comment: I do only need these during the recipe and expected the behavior you described but it failed in the way I described, let me revert back to that state (will take a little while) and post back the error, maybe I misread the cause there

Comment: I have updated the original post with the error that occurs without the File.exist? check. AFAICT, this is happening during the compilation phase due to the error message and because the file doesn't exist yet on the target system. So, since I do need the gem during the recipe, I think I have to use chef_gem and not gem_package and that is why this is failing since as you said, that tried to install during the compilation phase?

Comment: Yes, to use the gem from the recipe you'll have to use `chef_gem`, but means that it won't be available to install on the first run as `chef_gem`s are installed before other resources are run (i.e. during the compilation stage. So if you want to use chef to distribute the gems (instead of hosting them from a repository), you will have to run chef twice and check for the files existence unfortunately.